# Start countdown in current active element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have bootstrap multi-step form. There's 
`<span class="timer"></span>` at each step. 
My problem is that timer works only at first step. I don't know how to start countdown on another step (fieldset tag).
Timer code:

```
  var counter = seconds;

  var interval = setInterval(() => {
   document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = "("+counter + " seconds left)" ;

    counter--;
    if(counter < 0 ){
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, 1000);
};
```

I also tried this:

```
        $("#nextStep").click(function() {
            startCountdown(60);
        });
```

Comment: You say the element is `class="timer"`, yet you're using `getElementById()`..? Seeing a HTML sample would help clear the confusion here.

Comment: My mistake, this element has also timer ID @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('timer')` always returns the first item found in the DOM! you should use different id's (`#timer-1`, `#timer-2`, etc) and select them conditionally as you progress through each step.

you can augment your `startCountdown` method like this:

```
function startCountDown (selectorId, seconds) {
  var counter = seconds;

  var interval = setInterval(() => {
   document.getElementById(selectorId).innerHTML = "("+counter + " seconds left)" ;

    counter--;
    if(counter < 0 ){
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, 1000);
};

let idCounter = 0

$("#nextStep").click(function() {
   // generate new counter id based on your progression
   // this assumes your ids are timer-0, timer-1, etc
   startCountdown(60, 'timer-' + idCounter);
   idCounter++
});
```

Even better approach would be to use classes and `getElementsByClassName()` and then simply iterate over the array:

```
function startCountDown (selectorId, timerCounter, seconds) {
  var counter = seconds;

  var interval = setInterval(() => {
   // getElementsByClassName returns a DOMNodeList of matched items that you can use indexes to access
   document.getElementByClassName(selectorId)[timerCounter].innerHTML = "("+counter + " seconds left)" ;

    counter--;
    if(counter < 0 ){
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, 1000);
};

let timerCounter = 0

$("#nextStep").click(function() {
   startCountdown(60, 'timer', timerCounter);
   timerCounter++
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change  `<span class="timer"></span>` to  `<span id="timer"></span>`.
And with  `};` at the end in gives an error for me, so I used

```
var counter = seconds;

  var interval = setInterval(() => {
   document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = "("+counter + " seconds left)" ;

    counter--;
    if(counter < 0 ){
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, 1000);
```

instead of

```
var counter = seconds;

  var interval = setInterval(() => {
   document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = "("+counter + " seconds left)" ;

    counter--;
    if(counter < 0 ){
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, 1000);
};
```

You can do

```
var counter = seconds;
function startInterval() {
   var interval = setInterval(() => {
   document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = "("+counter + " seconds left)" ;

   counter--;
   if(counter < 0 ){
     clearInterval(interval);
   };
  }, 1000);
}
```

and use  `startInterval()` to start the timer.
If you need to do something when the timer seconds are over, you can do

```
var counter = seconds;
function startInterval() {
   var interval = setInterval(() => {
   document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = "("+counter + " seconds left)" ;

   counter--;
   if(counter < 0 ){
     clearInterval(interval);
     var timerOver = true;
   };
  }, 1000);
};
```